# How to add symboles on my scatterPlot using Swift

Tags: swift, core-plot

There isn't a lot of tutorial of how to use core-plot with Swift so can someone tell me how to implement symbolForScatterPlot function in Swift language please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol datasource method signature in Swift is:

```
func symbolForScatterPlot(plot: CPTPlot!, recordIndex: UInt) -> CPTPlotSymbol?
```

Return a plot symbol object or `nil` to omit the symbol at that index.